# How do I collate log files from different processes?

Tags: ruby, logging, syslog

I have a application written in Ruby which generates a log on `STDOUT`. The application would be running in multiple processes but I need to collate logs generated from each of the process into a single file. Is it possible?

I read somewhere that Syslog can be used for this but I am not sure how it can be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally decided to use log4r. It can collate logs from different processes and add them to the same log file.

Answer (score 1):

You don't say what OS you need this to work on, but for Linux and Mac OS, Ruby's `syslog` is a good candidate. I don't know if it's implemented on Windows, but I don't think it was.

The built-in documentation is not very good, but if you look at the source or "[Ruby Syslog README](http://glu.ttono.us/articles/2007/07/25/ruby-syslog-readme)" you'll get a good idea how to use it.

In the past I used the following code. For your purposes you'd want to reroute your output from STDOUT to this `syslog` method.

```
require 'syslog'

def syslog(msg, level=:info)

  # if msg is an array, we assume it is a cmd, message pair.
  if (msg.is_a?(Array))
    msg = msg.join(' => ')
  end

  # escape all '%' using '%%'
  msg.gsub!('%', '%%')

  Syslog.open($0) { |s|
    case level
    when :crit, :critical
      s.notice(msg)
    when :emerg, :emergency
      s.emerg(msg)
    when :alert
      s.alert(msg)
    when :err, :error
      s.err(msg)
    when :warn, :warning
      s.warning(msg)
    when :notice
      s.notice(msg)
    when :info, :information
      s.info(msg)
    when :debug, :debugging
      s.debug(msg)
    end
  }
end
```

Check the syslog man pages for information about the various logging levels.

`Syslog.open($0)` tells syslog to use the entire path to your application when inserting records. You might want to shrink `$0` to just the application name by using `Syslog.open(File.basename($0))`.